# MSSQL transaction replication - How to resync the data?

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have 1 transaction replication (peer to peer topology). After I setup, I found that the data on 2 table was difference.

The first peer table [VPMYN204].[AdventureWorks2019].[Person].[AddressType] have 6 rows.
And the second table [AdventureWorks2019].[Person].[AddressType] have 7 rows.

[image]

1. What should I do?
   (P/S: I am new to transaction replication feature.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen certain operations throw **Transactional Replication** out of whack before, and the first *turn it off, turn it on again* solution I'll go to when that happens is [**reinitializing the subscription**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/reinitialize-a-subscription?view=sql-server-ver15#to-mark-all-subscriptions-for-reinitialization-in-management-studio) for that **Publication**. Per the aforementioned documentation:

> Connect to the Publisher in Management Studio, and then expand the server node.

> Expand the Replication folder, and then expand the Local Publications folder.

> Expand the publication that has the subscription you want to reinitialize.

> Right-click the subscription, and then click Reinitialize.

> In the Reinitialize Subscription(s) dialog box, select options, and then click Mark for Reinitialization.

After that I'll usually monitor the [**snapshot agent status**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/monitor/monitor-replication-agents?view=sql-server-ver15#to-monitor-the-snapshot-agent-and-log-reader-agent) since the above generates a new snapshot that your **Transactional Replication Publication** will work off of, and I like to ensure it finishes replicating correctly.

After that's all done, you should be in sync now from the new snapshot, but you should try a data test, as I've seen worse cases where this didn't fix the issue. If you're still hosed at this point, you may have to drop and recreate your **Transactional Replication Publisher** and **Subscriber(s)**, unfortunately.

Comment: Seem like I have to drop and recreate. This is the error if I use reinitial-snapshot. "Cannot reinitialize the article 'all' in subscription 'VPMYN204:AdventureWorks2019' to publication 'Pub_AdvWork2019_4'. The publication is enabled for peer-to-peer transactional replication, which does not allow subscriptions to be reinitialized with a snapshot. Drop and re-create the subscription instead.
Changed database context to 'AdventureWorks2019'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

Comment: Beside this, may I know is that any feature that can use to detect the data variance on the 2 server tables?